# Is there a way to extend Codan ReturnChecker?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt

In `org.eclipse.cdt.codan.internal.core.CodanRunner` I found the following code:

```
CheckersRegistry chegistry = CheckersRegistry.getInstance();
```

chegistry contains a lot of Checkers, including a `ReturnChecker`.

```
...
for (IChecker checker : chegistry) {
    ...
    ((IRunnableInEditorChecker) checker).processModel(model, context);
    ...
}
```

This code eventually calls the `ReturnChecker`'s method to search in the statements in a function body (`IASTFunctionDefinition`) for a return statement. If that statement is missing, `reportNoRet()` is called. The editor marks the function with "No return, in function returning non-void".

Is there a way to override this ReturnChecker (or any other of the checkers) so that it only in some cases "reportNoRet" is not called? I also like to know if there is a way to add checkers (I couldn't find an extension point).

Answer (score 2):

You could try to extend the class to perform your own checks, but the basic checker will be always used. Maybe it would be better to create a new set of checkers for your language extension. Take a look [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/designs/StaticAnalysis), you find how to add new checkers.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely add new checkers. The extension point, as mentioned in **@greywolf82**'s link, is `org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.checkers`.

I'm not aware of a way to modify `ReturnChecker`'s behaviour in a more granular way that disabling specific problem types entirely. You're probably better off disabling `ReturnChecker`, and copying its code into your own checker with the desired modifications. (The disablement can also be done declaratively using the `org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.checkerEnablement` extension point.)